# Maven not resolving on Netbeans 7.2

Tags: java, maven, netbeans-7

I am very very new to Maven. I get the following error

```
 The following artifacts could not be resolved: stax:stax:jar:1.0, stax:stax-ri:jar:1.0, clover:clover:jar:1.3-rc4: Failure to find stax:stax:jar:1.0 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]

To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
```

After some research (e.g. [NetBeans: Re-run Maven with the -e switch on / PluginResolutionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702472/netbeans-re-run-maven-with-the-e-switch-on-pluginresolutionexception)), it is said that I need to edit my `~/.m2/settings.xml` file.

I look at the file and I don't see what to change. So I am including it below for input:

settings.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!--
User-specific configuration for maven. Includes things that should not
be distributed with the pom.xml file, such as developer identity, along with
local settings, like proxy information. The default location for the
settings file is ~/.m2/settings.xml
-->
<settings xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/SETTINGS/1.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/settings-1.0.0.xsd">
<!--proxies>
    <proxy>
        <host>my.proxy.host</host>
    </proxy>
</proxies-->

<!--pluginGroups>
    <pluginGroup>org.codehaus.mojo</pluginGroup>
</pluginGroups-->
```

POM.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.schoolsupplies.v5</groupId>
<artifactId>com.schoolsupplies.v5.test</artifactId>
<version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>com.schoolsupplies.v5.test</name>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.10</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
        <version>1.14</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jettison</groupId>
        <artifactId>jettison</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>dom4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>dom4j</artifactId>
    <version>20040902.021138</version>
    <type>jar</type>
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I open the dependencies directories and delete all the jars that were making trouble -- especially since they were not explicitly called for in the `pom.xml` file. After doing that, everything works fine.

It seems that maven decided that some of my explicitly imported dependencies needed those files. In my case: `stax:stax-ri:jar:1.0`, `clover:clover:jar:1.3-rc4`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I hade the same error. I added the repositories into the pom.xml and everything worked.

Like this example:

```
<repositories>
  <repository>
    <id>bukkit-repo</id>
    <url>http://repo.bukkit.org/content/groups/public/</url>
  </repository>
<repositories>
```