# Maven: Access POM at runtime - How to get 'pom.xml' available from anywhere?

Tags: java, maven, runtime, pom.xml

I want to access some information from the `pom.xml` to display in a Info dialog. So I googled and found [this post](https://riptutorial.com/maven/example/30104/reading-a-pom-xml-at-runtime-using-maven-model-plugin):

```
public class MavenModelExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, XmlPullParserException {
        MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
        Model model = reader.read(new FileReader("pom.xml"));
        System.out.println(model.getId());
        System.out.println(model.getGroupId());
        System.out.println(model.getArtifactId());
        System.out.println(model.getVersion());
    }
}
```

I implemented it in my tool, added

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
  <artifactId>maven-model</artifactId>
  <version>3.3.9</version>
</dependency>
```

to my pom and was happy that everything ran as expected when I run the tool from the project root directory with `java -jar target\mytool.jar`.

When I move to any other directory, e.g. directly into `target` and execute my tool with `java -jar mytool.jar`, I get:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: pom.xml (The system cannot find the specified file)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:213)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:155)
        at java.base/java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:110)
        at java.base/java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:60)
```

Which is kind of comprehensible. How should the code know, where the `pom.xml` is located, as it is not a resource. Is there any way to work around that?

In the mean time I use the approach from [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24749717/3154817) to obtain the version and artifactID.

Comment: Post the code so that SO members can help you.

Comment: I would try resource filtering instead of reading the POM. Which information do you need?

Comment: Currently I mainly want to retrieve the artifactID and version of my tool. But later I also want to access the dependency versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that

```
Model model = reader.read(new FileReader("pom.xml"));
```

tries to read the POM from the directory where your program is executed. Normally, `pom.xml` won't get copied to `target`, but it is embedded in the resulting artifact. You can override and force Maven to copy the POM to the `target` directory if you want to (for your own project), but it won't help you for other Maven artifacts.

Most of the time, a Maven artifact will have the POM coordinates included in the JAR/WAR/EAR output. If you unpack such a file, you'll notice that there are two files stored under `META-INF/maven/<groupId>/<artifactId>`: `pom.xml` and `pom.properties` where the latter is far easier to parse than `pom.xml` but it doesn't include the dependencies.

Parsing the embedded `pom.xml` from the classpath (and not from disk) should work better for you, especially if you always run your program with `java -jar target\mytool.jar`. In your program, try this:

```
try (InputStream is = MavenModelExample.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("META-INF/maven/<your groupId>/<your artifactId>/pom.xml")) {
            MavenXpp3Reader reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
            Model model = reader.read(is);
            System.out.println(model.getId());
            System.out.println(model.getGroupId());
            System.out.println(model.getArtifactId());
            System.out.println(model.getVersion());

            // If you want to get fancy:
            model.getDependencies().stream().forEach(System.out::println);  

        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            // Do whatever you need to do if the operation fails.
        }
```

`<your groupId>` and `<your artifactId>` should be fairly static, but if you do relocate your artifact's coordinates, then you need to change this in your code as well.

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'MavenXpp3Reader' do you have any solution? I used the dependency

Comment: Then you either have an import problem or the dependency is not on your classpath. It's impossible to tell without more information. And if you have more information, I would suggest that you create a new question specifically about your problem (how to reproduce it, output, configuration, code, etc).

Answer (score 0):

problem is that :

```
read(new FileReader("pom.xml"))
```

works fine when you start your application from STS or else, but when you build your application as JAR the path of the pom.xml file change to :

**META- INF/maven/${groupId}/${artifactId}/pom.xml**.

for that, try this code :

```
MavenXpp3Reader mavenXpp3Reader = new MavenXpp3Reader();
Model model;
if ((new File("pom.xml")).exists()) {
  model = mavenXpp3Reader.read(new FileReader("pom.xml"));
}
else {
 // Packaged artifacts contain a META- INF/maven/${groupId}/${artifactId}/pom.properties
  model = mavenXpp3Reader.read(new 
  InputStreamReader(Application.class.getResourceAsStream(
    "/META-INF/maven/groupId/artifactId/pom.xml")));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer; could you [edit] your answer to add a brief summary on how this helps solve the original question.

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'MavenXpp3Reader' do you know if still working?